# Tool to extract image metadata

Tags: java, image

I am looking for a tool/library for extracting metadata from images. The viewpoints are:

- command line/ java framework
- performance
- support
- production usage (we    need something which has already proven on
  production and used by big    companies)

I think ImageMAgick can be the right tool, but I could not find any references, who use it on prod

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: You might want to try Stack Exchange Photography  http://photo.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

Try this tool: [drewnoakes/metadata-extractor](https://github.com/drewnoakes/metadata-extractor) on GitHub.

Comment: Dunno why someone downvoted this, I voted it back up. It answers the OP question exactly.

Comment: thanks, it seems to be promising, but I could not find anything about production usage

Comment: It's a good library. I use it myself in my scala scrimage library.

Answer (score 1):

There are many tools and libraries that do this, however would it not make sense to stick with products that adhere to metadata standards?

For some ideas, go here:

http://forensicswiki.org/wiki/Document_Metadata_Extraction#Images
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensible_Metadata_Platform